# Sequelize.js postgres LATERAL usage

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgres table with JSONB field.
`json` contains array of objects

```
|  id  |                 my_json_field                |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1234 | [{"id": 1, type: "c"}, {"id": 2, type: "v"}] |
| 1235 | [{"id": 1, type: "e"}, {"id": 2, type: "d"}] |
```

I need to sort/filter table by `type` key of json field.
Server accept `id`, so if `id=1` - I need to sort by `"c","e"`, if `id=2` - by `"v","d"`

I have next SQL:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT elem ->> 'type' AS my_value
  FROM  jsonb_array_elements(my_json_field) a(elem)
  WHERE  elem ->> 'id' = '1'
) a ON true
```

this will add `my_value` field to the results and I can use it to sort/filter the table

This works fine in console, but I didn't find a way to add this using `Sequelize.js`

Also I'm open for any other solutions, thanks!

Edit, full query:

```
SELECT my_value FROM "main_table" AS "main_table"

LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "table2" AS "table2"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "form_table" AS "table2->form_table" ON "table2"."id" = "table2->form_table"."table2_id")
    ON "main_table"."id" = "table2"."main_table_id"

LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT elem ->> 'type' AS my_value
  FROM  jsonb_array_elements("table2->form_table".structure) a(elem)
  WHERE  elem ->> 'id' = '1'
) a ON TRUE

ORDER BY "my_value" DESC;
```

Comment: Additional note: using raw query can be difficult, since I have many relations and conditions for them

Comment: As not every database supports LATERAL that might have been a reason Sequelize didnt implement a native LATERAL way but iam pretty if you share your complete query and expected results it is most likely possible to rewrite this query

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've updated the question with full sql example

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the keyword `LATERAL` as that is implied if you use a set returning function directly and not in a sub-select.

The following should do the same thing as your query and doesn't need the LATERAL keyword:

```
SELECT a.elem ->> 'type' as my_value
FROM "main_table" 
  LEFT JOIN  "table2" ON "main_table"."id" = "table2"."main_table_id"
  LEFT JOIN "form_table" AS "table2->form_table" ON "table2"."id" = "table2->form_table"."table2_id")
  LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements("table2->form_table".structure) a(elem)  on a.elem ->> 'id' = '1'
ORDER BY my_value DESC;
```

I also removed the useless parentheses around the outer joins and the aliases that don't give the table a new name to simplify the syntax.

Maybe that allows you to use the query with your ORM (aka "obfuscation layer")